# Global read-only in Django Admin by group

Tags: django, django-admin

I need to be able to allow a staff member to be able to read everything in the Admin but not edit, add or delete. We have a non-admin interface that I've already done this via Group membership.

Is there something I can do for Admin without overriding *every* ModelAdmin?

Comment: Nope,  you can not do that without costomizing

Comment: You can create a custom, say, BaseModelAdmin in which you check if the logged in User is in a certain Group and set all fields to readonly in `__init__()`. Then subclass all Admin models from it.